# Trying to modify an array to avoid overlapping key-value pairs using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array([5258]=>5274,
      [5261]=>5281,
      [5264]=>5287,
      [5271]=>5289 );
```

I want to modify this array so that any overlaps in key value pairs are removed.

To elaborate, the first key value pair should become `[5258]=>5289`, because the numerical value of the each of the rest of the keys is less than 5274, the original value corresponding to the first key.

What would be the best way to do this using PHP? I'll appreciate some pointers on this.

Thanks.

EDIT: Just a reword to the background for my question:
If there's an array like this:

```
 Array([10]=>12
       [11]=>15
       [16]=>20)
```

I want to derive another array/modify the same array to get

```
 Array([10]=>15
       [16]=>20)
```

I hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: I read this like 5 times, and I still just don't get it.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me... why would the value of [5258] become 5289? What would [5261]'s value become?

Comment: Are you just trying to find the highest and lowest numbers in the key/values?  Perhaps a quick note about the context would help us understand...

Comment: Based on the original example, I would think the second would become `10=>20`? I'm glad I'm not alone in not understanding the plan here.

Comment: To add some weight to the other side: what's not to get? See it more as an array or `array($start,$end);` values instead of abusing the key and it may be clearer. Adjacency is also net enough for 'combining' ranges as I gather: the start must be equal or lower then the other's end, not 'the next in line'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a game of guess the actual question?

This is my answer to what I think the question is:

```
$arr = Array(
    5258=>5274,
    5261=>5281,
    5264=>5287,
    1=>100,
    50=>70,
    40=>130,
    5271=>5289
);

ksort($arr);
$out = array();
$start = null;
foreach ( $arr as $from=>$to )
{
    if ( $start === null )
    {
        $start = $from;
        $end = $to;
    } else {
        if ( $from < $end )
        {   
            $end = max($end,$to);
        } else {
            $out[$start] = $end; 
            $start = null; 
        }   
    }
}
if ( $start !== null ) $out[$start] = $end;

print_r($out);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 130
    [5261] => 5289
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. I'm tracing the code out too. Really sorry for not being clear in asking my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array(5258=>5274,
      5261=>5281,
      5264=>5287,
      5271=>5289 ,
      5301=>5400);

ksort($arr);
$new = array();
$currentkey   = reset(array_keys($arr));
$currentvalue = reset($arr);
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    if($key > $currentvalue){
        $new[$currentkey] = $currentvalue;
        $currentkey = $key;
    }
    $currentvalue = max($currentvalue,$value);
}
$new[$currentkey] = $currentvalue;
var_dump($new);
?>
```

Comment: this breaks on certain overlapping ranges

Comment: replace `$currentvalue = $value;` by `$currentvalue = max($currentvalue,$value);` to fix.

Comment: Ah, something which was not in the example indeed, will apply fix.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) but I'm not quite sure how it works. It's a bit black magic for me. At a guess, make a function which compares the key values and orders the array like that.

Or you could tinker with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array-merge)

Apologies for a waffling answer, I don't quite understand your question, or the criteria for how you want to merge/sort your array

Comment: `usort` works by calling your comparison function for each array item. Your function takes two arguments, each an array item. You compare the two how you wish and return -1 if the first should be first, 1 if the second should be first, and 0 if it doesn't matter. So, now that that's all set - `usort` wouldn't help because he wants to mix keys and values, not just sort an array. I think.

Comment: Neither has anything to do with the problem at hand indeed.